# Alfresco ldap sync without email property

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I need to sync alfresco 4.2 e with ldap without email property. Since the email address available in the ldap user property is not accurate, I need to sync everything except email. I then need to change the email address. But after ldap sync, the email property is not editable. I need to sync the ldap leaving email sync. So later the user can update her/his correct email address.

I tried

```
ldap.synchronization.userEmailAttributeName=

(or)

###ldap.synchronization.userEmailAttributeName=
```

Comment: Quick question: Why is the email address in LDAP not accurate at all and why isn't it fixed right there?

Comment: The ITTeam dont want to fix these email address for reason only they know

Comment: Ok. Unfortunately, when you synchronize users from LDAP / AD, Alfresco automatically considers fields such as email as "externally managed" / immutable.

Comment: My question is how are you getting LDAP sync to bring across the e-mail property to begin with?  My LDAP sync has the opposite problem, it refuses to bring the e-mail attribute, so I have to get every user to go in and edit their profile to add e-mail before I can invite them to sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can mark the email field as a non-mapped / mutable field by modifying / overriding the common-ldap-context.xml file and removing the

```
<entry key="cm:email">
    <!-- OpenLDAP: "mail" -->
    <!-- Active Directory: "???" -->
    <value>${ldap.synchronization.userEmailAttributeName}</value>
</entry>
```

configuration. This removes the "cm:email" field from the list of fields that are automatically marked as immutable when a user is sync'd from a LDAP / AD.